# Как вытащить из бд данные за определенный промежуток времени?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Подскажите, как нужно сделать, что бы из бд вытаскивались лишь данные за определенный промежуток времени. Мне нужно сделать, что бы из бд вытаскивались лишь данные за следующие 30 дней. То есть сейчас в ячейках есть записи, которые были добавлены ранее. 
Вот кусочек кода:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from user ORDER BY ref DESC limit 20 ");
$cont = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Сейчас он вытаскивает все записи... А как сделать как написано выше? Нужно создавать ячейку с временем?

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - "Нужно создавать ячейку с временем"

Comment: Если Вы не добавили время в таблицу, то как думаете, как оно угадает время? Внутри оно то, конечно, может и хранит время, но не обязано.

Comment: Ячейку с временем делать надо как не крути...

Answer (score 2):

Если данные в Юникс формате лежат, то так:

```
WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( curdate() - interval 30 day )
```